# mysql where lenght больше нуля. условие where не работает

Tags: mysql

есть таблица, в ней поле ( текстовое! т.е. text, не varchar ). делаю запрос

```
SELECT length(`har`) as `len`
FROM `catalog_kb`
WHERE `len` > 0
```

в результат идут все записи включая нули, т.е. where по сути не работает. Подскажите, как переписать запрос что бы заработало?

Comment: Поле выходного набора НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ в момент выполнения WHERE. Используйте HAVING.

Comment: оно! теперь буду знать. спс. ну надо это в ответы запостить, вдруг еще кому понадобиться